# Code Repositories - External API Call on Each Row of Dataset

Tags: rest, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a 2 step API call I need to make. I want to make it flexible for future use cases, however I am having trouble with it.

I make my initial get request to get the schema of the source data via REST API endpoint. The output of this will provide the input for the subsequent endpoint I will need to hit to get the data that is in each table.

Schema Endpoint Output:

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "id": "table1",
      "name": "A"
    },
    {
      "id": "table2",
      "name": "B"
    },
    {
      "id": "table3",
      "name": "C"
    },
    {
      "id": "table4",
      "name": "D"
    },
    {
      "id": "table5",
      "name": "E"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to hit another endpoint that takes that as an input and stores the output dynamically in another column. Ideal end state:

| tableID | tableName | tableData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | name A | json response 1 |
| table2 | name B | json response 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| tableN | name N | json response N |

I have been successful getting the first response, but when I put it in a pyspark dataframe I get errors when I try to hit each row to retrieve the data. Any ideas? I know there are a bunch of details missing, but maybe there is some general guidance since the documentation for this is lacking.

Transform steps:

1. Get schema and transform into a pyspark dataframe at first. Then tried following workflow with pandas dataframe in code repositories.
2. Unable to figure out how to use UDFs or just regular functions for hitting another endpoint for each row of the dataset.

Comment: What kind of error do you encounter ? Where ? What exactly did you try ? Is that an external source system you are trying to pull data from ? Which kind of implementation did you do so far ? (e.g. https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/ )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"... when I try to hit each row to retrieve the data"* - how?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar issue with a 2-step API call like this before. I solved it using *Data Connection Tasks*, which are not easy to find in documentation.

1. If your source data in the first API call is coming from a [data connection sync](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-connection/set-up-sync/) and is in a dataset, you just need to create a Data Connection Task for the second API call. Go to your data connector in its compass folder, *right-click* it, and click "Create Data Connection Task". You can then configure the API request in YAML, set the input dataset as your dataset from the first API call, and output to a new dataset containing the data from the second API call. Build this output dataset to run the Data Connection Task. For the YAML configuration, you can open the configuration of your original Data Connector Sync in *Advanced* mode, and copy the YAML there for the formatting.
2. If your source data is not coming from a data connection sync, I would recommend migrating it to one, rather than making the API calls directly in the code. This way you can better set up schedules and health checks around your API calls in the sync, rather than having it embedded in your code. You'll also be able solve your issue by following my recommendations above.

After collecting the data from both steps of the API calls, you can then join those datasets together as you like to achieve the format of your ideal end state.